# Perl network frame/packet parser

Tags: perl, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I am writing a small sniffer as part of a personal project. I am using `Net::Pcap` (really really great tool).

In the packet-processing loop I am using the excellent `Net::Frame` for unpacking all the headers and getting at the data. I am getting concerned that this might not be terribly efficient (`Net::Frame` is great but seems to be more than I need for this project).

Also I dislike that for some Debian systems I had to manually compile libdumbnet (the package provided in the official apt repositories didn't seem to work, `Net-Libdnet-0.92` didn't like it).

All I want is to get at the payload inside a TCP segment. Is there any alternative ?
Thank you.

P.S. Would it be really really bad (read "thedailywtf.com worthy") if I just took the packet and searched it for some pattern ?

Comment: I guess unpack() would be a better idea than RE to deal with TCP packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a PCAP dump file unpacker in C and then afterwards wished I'd just used the open source libraries instead (when I realised they existed and were so easy to use). I have to say that as it's a binary file format it's probably easier to do in C than Perl, but I'll no doubt get boo'ed by all the Perl fanatics out there.

What I will say is that using existing code will be quicker all round than coding it yourself, but if you really really want to, the file format is freely available online and is really quite simple.

As for searching for a pattern, it almost certainly won't work. It's a binary file format and the packets can be fragmented and/or duplicated, so the only reliable way to know where a message starts and ends is by unpacking the headers, checking the packet flags, reading the content length field, etc. etc. Doing pattern searches may work 90% of the time, but at some point you'll find a packet capture log that means you need to change your code. And then a while later find another packet that means another change, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Just curious: what open source libraries do you wish you had used ?

Comment: libpcap. It's the underlying PCAP library used by tcpdump, Wireshark, etc. etc. It's probably also the underlying library for Net::Pcap and Net::Frame too.